# Changing casing of data in a column

Tags: mysql

I need to reformat the data in column uk_city, right now all row entries are in Uppercase I want to reformat to FirstChr uppercase and the other lower case.

```
FELTON to Felton
FENNY COMPTON to Fenny Compton
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post a function found [here](http://joezack.com/index.php/2008/10/20/mysql-capitalize-function/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))

RETURNS VARCHAR(255)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET input = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(input,i),
                    UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN input;
END;
```

If you create this function in your database, you can do

```
UPDATE uk_city SET name = CAP_FIRST(name);
```